# Showing GIF image at the time of the Upload

Tags: asp.net

HI,

I am working on Asp.net 2.0 and C#.

I stuck with one issue.

I want to upload the file (Large file through upload control in asp.net). but at the time of uploading, want to see a animated gif image (In Process). 
I don't want to use Ajax and third party tool to upload. It's in plain asp.net 2.0.

I heard that, through threading it's possible. I tried but no luck... :(

Can anyone please help me out from this problem?

Thanks In Advance...

Mahesh

Comment: Could you perhaps show us what you've tried thus far to give a better indication of what you're attempting to achieve?  Are you wanting the uploading image to be the process animation or something like a spinning hour glass?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an issue with IE that prevents animated gifs from fully rendering during upload; it simply shows first frame.

Instead display **flash** animation, it will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If you were creating a windows thick client (winform/WPF) then yes a thread would work. ASP.NET is an entirely different beast. It does not have threading (at least in the html) and on the server threading is discouraged because of the possible side effects as the server scales.

What you are trying to do **can't** be done with **out of the box** components. To do what you want you must use some sort of javascript. I would look at [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/). It's simple, easy to use and fits your needs.

If you need the server side code I can post it.